# Angular template, check if DOM element is a specific ElementRef

Tags: angular, templates, dom

I would like to check in a template if an element in a loop is a specific ElementRef

For example:

Controller:

```
@Component({selector: 'someCmp', templateUrl: 'someCmp.html'})
class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(el) elList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  public element: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.element = this.elList.toArray()[2];
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div #el *ngFor="[...]" [ngClass]="this === element ? 'highlight' : ''"></div>
<div #el *ngFor="[...]" [ngClass]="this === element ? 'highlight' : ''"></div>
```

Of course it doesn't work, "this" isn't the ElementRef.

Is there a way to detect that ?

I don't want to check by Index because I can have multiple loops in template side, like in my example

And oh, I'm using Angular 8 :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the ideal solution would be that you can define class name for each `div` in your `*ngFor=[....]` array, so you can call it `<div #el *ngFor="item of [...]" [ngClass]="item.className ? 'highlight' : ''"></div>`

If you absolutely want to compare element, you may want to do it in TypeScript though, instead of in template. As blow code.

```
  @ViewChildren('el', {read: ElementRef})
  ele: QueryList<ElementRef>

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    /** A mock selectElement */
    const selectElement = this.ele.toArray()[2];

   /** Upate elements everytime elements get changed. */
    this.ele.changes.pipe(
      startWith(this.ele),
      map(elements => elements.toArray()),
    ).subscribe(elements => {
      elements.map((element: ElementRef) => {
        if (element === selectElement) {
          /** Modify elements */
          this.renderer.addClass(element.nativeElement, 'highlight');
        }
      })
    });
  }
```